# Form action in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem in my form action in Spring MVC.

My code:

```
<form method="POST" action="j_acegi_security_check" name="frmLogin">
    <input type='hidden'  autocomplete="off" name='_schema' id="_schema"/>
    <input type='hidden'  id='j_username' name='j_username'  autocomplete="off"  /> 
    <input type='hidden'  id='j_password' name='j_password' autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

I can't understand what kind of action is `j_acegi_security_check` perfoming.

Comment: That is the login from the webserver

Comment: Have you tried debugging? If you know the controller bring called, use your IDE's inbuilt debugger to know the exact execution path. Or simply search your whole project for that action path mapping. Additionally, your code seems wrong.

Comment: it works correctly........nothing wrong about my code

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

For Form Action, you need to land your request to the controller you created for. Specify your request name for example

This is HTML part  `<form:form method = "POST"action="/addUser">...</form:form>`

For your controller class

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")User user, 
   ModelMap model) {       

}
```

Your request will be landed to this controller where you can perform any desired action.

Hope this will help.

Comment: its spring security based cofiguration. it does not have request mapping...

Comment: But maybe the main problem is that you use an old spring acegi security and not the actual spring security 3.x. It this is the case, than the statement above is my not true. So I recommend to update!

In case of Spring ACEGI 1.0.x

Try to override the attemptAuthentication method in AuthenticationProcessingFilter with something like this:

if (request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
   return super.attemptAuthentication(request);
else
   throw new AuthenticationServiceException("service accept only http post");

Comment: If that does not solves your problem, please mention your steps you are doing, and the web server deploying at.